# How do I get easy_install to install modules to the correct directory?

Tags: python, easy-install

I am trying to install a new module with easy_install.

When I run a command like

```
sudo easy_install foo
```

foo gets installed to `~/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`.

This seems to be wrong since I can't use any of the installed modules from within my python shell.

From what I have understood after reading through some SO posts related to easy_install issues the correct directory should be `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
, since my python shell uses `/usr/local/bin/python` which is symbolically linked to said directory.

How do I tell easy_install to use this directory rather then the current one?

Thank you,

Julian

**EDIT:** I reran the setuptools installation with the option `-d /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. The output was as follows:

```
Processing setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Removing /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Copying setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
setuptools 0.6c11 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing easy_install script to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Installing easy_install-2.7 script to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for setuptools==0.6c11
Finished processing dependencies for setuptools==0.6c11
```

The output of e.g. `sudo easy_install mechanize` is

```
Searching for mechanize
Best match: mechanize 0.2.5
Processing mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg
mechanize 0.2.5 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Users/julian/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for mechanize
Finished processing dependencies for mechanize
```

It seems that easy_install is still using the wrong directory?! Help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was having an issue with my PATH. Moving `/usr/local/share/python` to the top of my PATH and reinstalling python through homebrew fixed my problems.

In case the problem persists, definitely try running `brew doctor` and follow the advice there!

Answer (score 3):

You can use --prefix to set the path where you want to install a package. Or add /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ to your python path.

Comment: I tried adding /Users/myuser/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ via `import sys  sys.path.append('...')` but when I restart the shell and print sys.path the directory I just added isn't being listed. This all seems very weird.

Comment: Yes, if you do sys.path.append() it will only stay there for the duration of your shell session. You will want to add it to your .bashrc file in your home directory. Do cd / -> nano (or vim or whatever you find easiest) .bashrc -> paste this in there: 

 export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ -> save

Comment: I added this to my .profile but am still facing the same problem. Is there a way to see where easy_install is writing its changes?

Comment: When I run `sudo easy_install mechanize -d /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages `The output is: `Searching for -d
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/-d/
Couldn't find index page for '-d' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for -d
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('-d')`

Comment: the -d should probably be in front of mechanize, as in `sudo easy_install -d /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages mechanize`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to install setuptools(which has easy_install) for the python install you're trying to use. So, using your symlinked python, follow [these instructions](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools), then, use the `easy_install` in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Scripts` rather than `~/Library/Python/2.7/Scripts`

Comment: I ran the setuptools-installation with -d set to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages` but I still can't access the installed modules. It isn't giving me any error messages but I'm not sure if the installation has changed anything.

Comment: could you try `sudo /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Scripts/easy_install mechanize` instead of the typical easy_install in your path? I'm not 100% sure that that's the right directory, since I've never used python on a Mac. Otherwise I don't know what else to try.

Comment: This produces the following output:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy_install-2.7", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c11', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install-2.7')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'easy_install-2.7') not found`

Comment: Yeah, setuptools is weird. This solution probably won't work then.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify an installation directory with --install-dir=DIR

check out http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html#command-line-options for more fancy options! One thing to note though is that the directory you specify must be on your python path.